# Can somebody edit this so it works

Tags: exam

```
\documentclass{article}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\Alph{choice}}
\newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice.}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{choices}%
  {\list{\choicelabel}%
     {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
       \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 2.5em}%
       \def\choice{%
         \item
       } % choice
       \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
       \topsep=0pt
       \partopsep=0pt
     }%
  }%
  {\endlist}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\CorrectChoice{%
      \choice
      \addanswer{\thequestion}{\thechoice}%
    }
    \let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice
%    \par % Uncomment this to have choices always start a new line
   % \let\par\@empty
    % If we're continuing the paragraph containing the question,
    % then leave a bit of space before the first choice:
    \ifvmode\else\enskip\fi
    \ignorespaces
  %
  {}
\makeatother
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{}
\newcommand{\addanswer}[2]{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{\unhbox\allanswers \quad #1.~#2}%
}
\newcommand{\showanswers}{%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    Answers
  \end{center}
  \unhbox\allanswers
}





%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \correctchoice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{choices}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{choices}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?

  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?

  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{choices}
\end{enumerate}

\showanswers
\end{document}
```

Comment: Posting an MWE is often a necessary but not a sufficient condition to get answers on this site. You should at least describe the errors you're getting...

Answer (score 8):

Since you are numbering the questions using a standard `enumerate`, you need to use the `\theenumi` and not `\thequestion` (which will trigger an error since no `question` counter was defined) in `\addanswer`, so you need

```
\addanswer{\theenumi}{\thechoice}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\Alph{choice}}
\newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice.}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{choices}%
  {\list{\choicelabel}%
     {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
       \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 2.5em}%
       \def\choice{%
         \item
       } % choice
       \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
       \topsep=0pt
       \partopsep=0pt
     }%
  }%
  {\endlist}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\CorrectChoice{%
      \choice
      \addanswer{\theenumi}{\thechoice}%
    }
    \let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice
%    \par % Uncomment this to have choices always start a new line
   % \let\par\@empty
    % If we're continuing the paragraph containing the question,
    % then leave a bit of space before the first choice:
    \ifvmode\else\enskip\fi
    \ignorespaces
  %
  {}
\makeatother
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{}
\newcommand{\addanswer}[2]{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{\unhbox\allanswers \quad #1.~#2}%
}
\newcommand{\showanswers}{%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    Answers
  \end{center}
  \unhbox\allanswers
}





%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \correctchoice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \correctchoice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{choices}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \correctchoice White
  \end{choices}
\item One of these things is not like the others; one of these things
  is not the same.  Which one doesn't belong?

  \begin{choices}
    \choice George
    \choice Paul
    \choice John
    \choice Ringo
    \choice Socrates
  \end{choices}
\item What was the color of George Washinton's white horse?

  \begin{choices}
    \choice Green
    \choice Yellow
    \choice White
  \end{choices}
\end{enumerate}

\showanswers
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder why aren't you using a dedicated class (such as [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam)) or package ([`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets), for example) which offer you the functionality that you are building as well as many other ready to use features.

Comment: @ManojKumar You're welcome! By the way, don't forget that you can accept answers that best solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to their left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).